# A riddle where the answer seems to be one thing but is another

Tags: riddle, puzzle-creation

For a project I'm doing I need a "trick" riddle - one where the first answer most people would think of is **wrong**, and the **true** answer is something else entirely that isn't *way too hard* to come up with (bonus points if the true answer seems obvious after you know it).

I tried google but couldn't find anything like this. Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions!

Comment: Are you looking to make your own, or are you just looking for one you can reuse?

Comment: Here's a recent riddle one of mine that I tried to make in that way: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/69173/36023

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like the old standard: "What do men do standing up, women do sitting down, and dogs do on three legs?" The answer being: "Shake hands."

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite fitting, but still: 
All of my pets but two are cats, 
All of my pets but two are hamsters, 
All of my pets but two are dogs; 
How many pets do I have?

Comment: Is it 3? Got a little curious now

Comment: @S.M. No, actually I hold two snakes.